# In Azure, is there a way to maintain a current external/polybase table while also maintaining history for rolling back transactions?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, azure-synapse

I have a Delta Table in Azure Databricks that stores history for every change that occurs.  I also have a polybase external table for the users to read from in an Azure SQL Data Warehouse/Azure Synapse.  But when an update or delete is necessary, I have to vacuum the table in order to update the polybase to the latest, or it has a copy from every previous version.  That vacuum, by nature, deletes the history, so I can no longer roll back.

I'm thinking my only choice is to manually keep a row change table with colums = [schema_name, table_name, primary_key, old_value, new_value] so that we can reapply the changes in reverse if necessary.  Is there anything more elegant I can do?

Comment: Would querying your delta table in a separate serverless SQL pool be adequate? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-delta-lake-format

Comment: Do you mean replacing the polybase external tables with that?  I'm afraid I cannot replace that part of the system.

Comment: right. Is that because you have other (non-external) tables in your dedicated SQL pool?